# Unexpected identifier "let" in linux node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, express, mean-stack

I have one loop in node.js looking like

```
for(let i=0; i < req.body.Node_Config.length;i++){

//code

}
```

working perfectly in windows

But when I've uploaded it onto a linux based webserver than it has given me error

```
 for(let i=0; i < req.body.Node_Config.length;i++){
         ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/OSPL_node/app.js:33:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
```

Comment: update node to latest version, old versions do not support es6 syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not about the OS, it should be the same.

I think it is because of the Node version, make sure it is the same in both cases.

In particular you should use a Node.js with a version compatible with `ES6`, in your code it's failing because it does not recognize `let`.

[Here](http://node.green/#bindings) you have a list of versions compatibles with `let`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Antonio Val please can you let me know how can i replace "let" with any other

Comment: You can update Node.js version, or you just can use `var` to make sure it works even with old versions. In your code it would be: `for(var i=0; i < req.body.Node_Config.length;i++){`

Comment: My loop is made as that var will make disaster thanks I'll update node..

Comment: You are welcome!

If it helped please choose the answer as the "accepted answer".

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and probably best way, as Antonio's answer says, is to upgrade Node.

But in case that's not possible, another way would be to use a transpiler like Babel to turn your ES2016 code into ES5 code that older Node versions can understand. You might also need some polyfill library like babel-polyfill to provide support for missing functionality.